# Append URL's in a given substring from a range of integers

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to format the URL's of a given file.

The URL's have this format:

> http://randomtext&of=randomtext&=.com

There is an init method that reads the url's from a file:

```
  def __init__(self,filename=None):
    if filename:
        with open('urls.txt') as f:
            self.start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
```

I can append on the end of the url with a range of integers:

```
    def __init__(self,filename=None):
    if filename:
        with open('urls.txt') as f:
            self.start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
            self.start_urls = [url + str(i*10) for i in range(0,25) for url in self.start_urls]
```

My question is how to append the string on the substring 'of=' on the above URL's with a number of integers eg:

1. http://randomtext&of=1randomtext
2. http://randomtext&of=2randomtext
3. http://randomtext&of=3randomtext

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the sub() function from pythons re-module to replace the numbers in the urls with your numbers from a given range.
So build upon your provided example, one possible solution could be this:

```py
import re

def __init__(self,filename=None):
    if filename:
        with open('urls.txt') as f:
            self.start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
            self.start_urls = [re.sub("[0-9][0-9]*", str(i*10), url) for i in range(0,25) for url in self.start_urls]
```

You may want to check if there are other numbers in your urls that you don't want to be substituted and change the regex accordingly.